# How to prevent my EC2 instances from automatically rebooting every time one has stopped?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, kubernetes, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-eks

**UPDATED**

Following the [AWS instance scheduler](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PitS8RiyDv8) I've been able to setup a scheduler that starts and stops at the beginning and end of the day.

However, the instances keep being terminated and reinstalled.

I have an Amazon Elastic Kubernetes Service (EKS) that returns the following CloudWatch log:
discovered the following log in my CloudWatch

```
13:05:30
2019-11-21 - 13:05:30.251 - INFO : Handler SchedulerRequestHandler scheduling request for service(s) rds, account(s) 612681954602, region(s) eu-central-1 at 2019-11-21 13:05:30.251936
13:05:30
2019-11-21 - 13:05:30.433 - INFO : Running RDS scheduler for account 612681954602 in region(s) eu-central-1
13:05:31
2019-11-21 - 13:05:31.128 - INFO : Fetching rds Instances for account 612681954602 in region eu-central-1
13:05:31
2019-11-21 - 13:05:31.553 - INFO : Number of fetched rds Instances is 2, number of schedulable resources is 0
13:05:31
2019-11-21 - 13:05:31.553 - INFO : Scheduler result {'612681954602': {'started': {}, 'stopped': {}}}
```

I don't know if it is my EKS that keeps rebooting my instances, but I really would love to keep them stopped until the next day.

How can I prevent my EC2 instances from automatically rebooting every time one has stopped? Or, even better, how can I deactivate my EKS stack automatically?

**Update:**

I discovered that EKS has a Cluster Autoscaler. Maybe this could be where the problem lies?
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/cluster-autoscaler.html

Answer (score 1):

EKS node group would create an auto scaling group to manage the worker nodes. You need specify the minimum, maximum and desired size of worker nodes. Once any instance is stopped, the auto scaling group would create new instance to match the desired instance size.

Check below doc for details,

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/launch-workers.html

Comment: The min, max and desired have all been set. However, I currently have to change the min and desired manually to 0 if I want to deactivate my instances. I want to be able to disable my instances automatically with the scheduler. E.g.: It's 20h, the scheduler detects that it has to deativate the ec2 instances. It does that and also sets the min and desired of the auto scaling group to 0 to avoid the ec2s from being recreated. How can this be done?

Comment: You might have a try using cloudwatch fixed scheduler to scale up/down the autoscaling group.

Comment: I will look into that. Thank you!